# Compare uniqueidentifier in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

We have two tables : `MainTable` and `CloneOfMainTable`

The structure of both tables is :

```
ID : int Identity Primarykey
Foo: nvarchar(50) 
RowVersion : uniqueidentifier
```

We want to simply get the updated rows by comparing RowVersion and bla bla ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM MainTable 
INNER JOIN CloneOfMainTable On MainTable.ID = CloneOfMainTable.ID
WHERE MainTable.RowVersion <> CloneOfMainTable.RowVersion
```

and it doesn't work ^_^"

Comment: How _exactly_ it does not work? Do you get any error messages? Does the result of the select differ from what you expect, and how? Explain better for a chance to get a better answer.

Comment: nah , just it doesn't return any result , the where clause part doesn't work

Comment: are you sure you should get results?

Comment: yep , I'm sure ! and one more thing the RowVersion Is nullable

Comment: Can it be that one of the sides in the `MainTable.RowVersion <> CloneOfMainTable.RowVersion` is always `null`, so that the comparison always yields false?

Comment: that's right , it can't compare null uniqueidentifier , i have to check it manually Q,Q sux!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no limitations on comparing uniqueidentifier values. As the column is nullable you may use `coalesce` to include `null` values in comparison:

```
WHERE coalesce(MainTable.RowVersion,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') <> coalesce(CloneOfMainTable.RowVersion,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
```