# Assign query value to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having real trouble assigning the return value of a query to a variable in a stored procedure, here is what I have:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateTaskFromProposalStatusUpdate]
@proposalstatusupdateid uniqueidentifier

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @owninguser uniqueidentifier
SET @owninguser = '07da8e53-74bd-459c-af94-a037897a51e3' -- todo set to salesperson

DECLARE @name nvarchar(300)
SET @name = 'test name'

DECLARE @accountid uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @accountcontacts varchar(100)

SET @accountid = NEWID()
SET @accountcontacts = CAST(@proposalstatusupdateid as VARCHAR(36))

DECLARE @proposalid uniqueidentifier
--SET @proposalid = (SELECT new_propstatusupdateid FROM new_proposalstatusupdate WHERE New_proposalstatusupdateId = @proposalstatusupdateid)
SELECT @proposalid = new_propstatusupdateid FROM new_proposalstatusupdate WHERE New_proposalstatusupdateId = @proposalstatusupdateid

INSERT INTO ActivityPointerBase
(OwningBusinessUnit,
ActivityId,
IsBilled,
CreatedBy,
[Description],
DeletionStateCode,
ModifiedOn,
ActivityTypeCode,
StateCode,
ScheduledEnd,
ScheduledDurationMinutes,
ActualDurationMinutes,
StatusCode,
ActualStart,
CreatedOn,
PriorityCode,
RegardingObjectId,
[Subject],
IsWorkflowCreated,
ScheduledStart,
ModifiedBy,
OwningUser,
RegardingObjectTypeCode,
RegardingObjectIdName,
TimeZoneRuleVersionNumber,
RegardingAccountId,
RegardingAccountTelephone)
VALUES
('C5B71CA7-1230-4D2A-8DEA-26184EA5E262',
NEWID(),
0,
@owninguser,
'002 Proposal {decision} with {funder} B',
0,
GETDATE(),
4212,
0,
GETDATE(),
0,
1,
1,
GETDATE(),
GETDATE(),
1,
@proposalid,
'002 Proposal {decision} with {funder} B',
0,
GETDATE(),
@owninguser,
@owninguser,
10011,
@name,
0,
@accountid,
@accountcontacts)
```

I've tried both methods above to try and set it but they both result in `@proposalid` being `NULL`.

I've checked the `@proposalstatusupdateid` parameter is coming through and that's fine, and trying the query manually always returns a result.

Not sure what's wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT new_propstatusupdateid FROM new_proposalstatusupdate WHERE New_proposalstatusupdateId = @proposalstatusupdateid` Any results for this query ?

Comment: You can try execute SP by running the SQL Profiler. Monitor the actual select query that executes on database with the help of profiler. May be it is returning no value with filter @proposalstatusupdateid ...

Comment: One more question, where are you returning this variable ? if you are not returning this, then write "SELECT @proposalid" to print it on result grid when SP executes ...

Comment: @Prdp yes, running that query manually returns a result

Comment: @Ben - After this select query any where else down the procedure variable might have got re-initialised check that as well

Comment: In that case sql is not returning any results ... Check comment from @Prdp

Comment: @Ben - what is the datatype of `new_propstatusupdateid` column ?

Comment: @prdp uniqueidentifer

Comment: new_propstatusupdateid is nullable ???? if yes then following link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731416/compare-uniqueidentifier-in-where-clause

Comment: @Ben - Query looks fine nothing wrong. I tested it could not replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to either RETURN that value or make a resultset

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateTaskFromProposalStatusUpdate]
@proposalstatusupdateid uniqueidentifier

AS

DECLARE @proposalid uniqueidentifier
--SET @proposalid = (SELECT new_propstatusupdateid FROM new_proposalstatusupdate WHERE New_proposalstatusupdateId = @proposalstatusupdateid)
SELECT @proposalid = new_propstatusupdateid FROM new_proposalstatusupdate WHERE New_proposalstatusupdateId = @proposalstatusupdateid

SELECT @proposalid as new_propstatusupdateid
```

Comment: I use it as part of an insert to another table, but it's value is always null

Comment: if New_proposalstatusupdateId is nullable then it may cause problem. so use isnull(New_proposalstatusupdateId,'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')=proposalstatusupdateid to compare instead

Answer (score 0):

you can use a output parameter

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateTaskFromProposalStatusUpdate]
    @proposalstatusupdateid uniqueidentifier,
    @Proposalid_out out

    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @owninguser uniqueidentifier
    SET @owninguser = '07da8e53-74bd-459c-af94-a037897a51e3' -- todo set to salesperson

    DECLARE @name nvarchar(300)
    SET @name = 'test name'

    DECLARE @accountid uniqueidentifier
    DECLARE @accountcontacts varchar(100)

    SET @accountid = NEWID()
    SET @accountcontacts = CAST(@proposalstatusupdateid as VARCHAR(36))

    DECLARE @proposalid uniqueidentifier
    --SET @proposalid = (SELECT new_propstatusupdateid FROM new_proposalstatusupdate WHERE New_proposalstatusupdateId = @proposalstatusupdateid)
    SELECT @proposalid = new_propstatusupdateid FROM new_proposalstatusupdate WHERE New_proposalstatusupdateId = @proposalstatusupdateid

    INSERT INTO ActivityPointerBase
    (OwningBusinessUnit,
    ActivityId,
    IsBilled,
    CreatedBy,
    [Description],
    DeletionStateCode,
    ModifiedOn,
    ActivityTypeCode,
    StateCode,
    ScheduledEnd,
    ScheduledDurationMinutes,
    ActualDurationMinutes,
    StatusCode,
    ActualStart,
    CreatedOn,
    PriorityCode,
    RegardingObjectId,
    [Subject],
    IsWorkflowCreated,
    ScheduledStart,
    ModifiedBy,
    OwningUser,
    RegardingObjectTypeCode,
    RegardingObjectIdName,
    TimeZoneRuleVersionNumber,
    RegardingAccountId,
    RegardingAccountTelephone)
    VALUES
    ('C5B71CA7-1230-4D2A-8DEA-26184EA5E262',
    NEWID(),
    0,
    @owninguser,
    '002 Proposal {decision} with {funder} B',
    0,
    GETDATE(),
    4212,
    0,
    GETDATE(),
    0,
    1,
    1,
    GETDATE(),
    GETDATE(),
    1,
    @proposalid,
    '002 Proposal {decision} with {funder} B',
    0,
    GETDATE(),
    @owninguser,
    @owninguser,
    10011,
    @name,
    0,
    @accountid,
    @accountcontacts)
SET @Proposalid_out = proposalid
```

/***********Calling **************************/

```
DECLARE @Proposalid_out uniqueidentifier
EXEC sp_CreateTaskFromProposalStatusUpdate
        @proposalstatusupdateid uniqueidentifier,
        @Proposalid_out out
SELECT @Proposalid_out
```

/**************************************************************